# Detach running programe from bash

Tags: bash, putty

I'm often in the situation that I run a linux task but then I have to leave the computer or shutdown the notebook, and the task I ran from putty has not finished yet.

Is there a way of I can quit putty and leave the process running 'til it's finished?

I know I can use `screen` etc, but now I already started the command w/o `screen`.

*(please don't bother too much I didnt directly ask on superuser, serverfault or unix SO.)*

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/96660/how-can-i-keep-a-process-alive-after-closing-the-putty-session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press `Ctrl-Z` to put the command to background.

Run `bg` to run it from being suspended.

Then run `disown` to disown the process from the parent.

It actually also depends on how your command works. Some command exits when it loses its terminal. If that's the case, you can really only just run it with `screen` or use `nohup command </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &`.

One way to run it with screen could be `screen -dm command`.

Comment: when I ran the first 3 commands (which work, thx), is there I way I can bring the process back to the foreground when I reconnect?